# Why is zod removing a valid property when `parse`ing?

Tags: zod

I am using `schema.parse` to validate user input and Zod is removing a valid property from the value I pass into the `parse` function.

This seems to be related to using `.or`. Here is the code:

```js
const z = require('zod')

const baseSchema = z.object({})

const extendedSchema = baseSchema.extend({
  a: z.string()
})

const optionsSchema = baseSchema.or(extendedSchema)

const options = {
  a: 'A'
}

console.log('before `schema.parse`', JSON.stringify(options))      // prints: before `schema.parse` {"a":"A"}
const validOptions = optionsSchema.parse(options)
console.log('-after `schema.parse`', JSON.stringify(validOptions)) // prints: -after `schema.parse` {}
```

In the example above, I don't understand why the `a` prop is being removed.

Am I misunderstanding how `.or` works? Is this a bug in Zod? What's going on?

---

I have a [minimal reproduction repo](https://github.com/shawninder/zod-issue-repro-parse-removes-prop) you can clone, install and run if you want to see this happening for yourself.

Comment: What if you reorder it to `const optionsSchema = extendedSchema.or(baseSchema)`?

Comment: Changing the order as @Samathingamajig suggests works for me. It also seems to work with multiple extended schemas, although only when the base schema is last. See my tests [here](https://github.com/shawninder/zod-issue-repro-parse-removes-prop/blob/order-matters/index.js#L31).

Comment: @Samathingamajig if you make this an answer I'll accept it and tick the checkmark and you can get your rep. Extra points if you can explain why only base-schema-last works and what this means for more complex examples with multiple base schemas for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without looking at the source code, I'm 99% sure that it is a [shortcircuiting OR operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR#short-circuit_evaluation) that only copies the specified properties.

Short-circuiting OR means that once it finds the first matching schema it will immediately return and not check any others.

The order of checking is based on the order you call `.or`.

For example, if you had schemas `A`, `B`, and `C`, where `C` extends `B` and `B` extends `A`,

```js
const optionsSchema = A.or(B).or(C); // equal to A.or(B.or(C));
// and
const optionsSchema = A.or(C).or(B);
```

will always match `A`, even if `B` or `C` are more specific, or not at all

```js
const optionsSchema = B.or(C).or(A);
// and
const optionsSchema = B.or(A).or(C);
```

will match `B` if it can (even if `C` is more specific), otherwise check `A`, or nothing at all

```js
const optionsSchema = C.or(A).or(B);
```

will match `C` if it can, otherwise check for and match `A` (even if `B` is more specific), or nothing at all

```js
const optionsSchema = C.or(B).or(A);
```

will match `C` if it can, otherwise check for and match `B`, otherwise check for and match `A`, or nothing at all.

`Schema.parse(...)` does not just echo the object, it returns a copy of the object based on the keys of the schema (and makes any modifications specified by [`.transform`](https://zod.dev/?id=transform) and related methods).

Even by switching the order around,

```js
const validOptions = optionsSchema.parse(options);

console.log(options == validOptions);
```

outputs `false`.

In your case, it matched the schema of an object with no properties (`baseSchema`), because zod doesn't care about extra properties. It doesn't delete the unused properties per se, it just returns a "copy" that doesn't have any keys assigned to it.

Comment: what is the solution then ?